# How to get yahooID when I got a valid token?

Tags: yahoo-oauth

I use BBAuth (yahoo authentication) in my website, when user sign in with their yahoo account,when it is successful (redirect to end point url), I would like to get yahoo id account to insert into my db, I can't find any method or property to get it.

Please tell me how to get yahoo id when they are successful login my system.

Thanks all,
Nguyen

Answer (score 1):

You can't - the info is not exposed via the BBAuth API.

Comment: Thank CodeByMoonlight for your response,

But how can I insert into my database with email field? OR send welcome email message?

http://noi.vn (they did it)

Thanks & Regards,

Nguyen

Comment: I don't know without signing up to it to see how. All i see is a page in vietnamese that has bbAuth in the address, but given that the Google login is using OpenID and Yahoo supports it too, they might actually be using that instead.